# Python Как удалить текст после определенного символа?

Tags: python, парсер, текст

Я пишу парсер для одного сайта, и мне нужно взять год автомобиля.
Но на сайте помимо года дальше идет ещё текст, который мне нужно обрезать
Выглядит он так:
**2005 (first reg. 1-2005)**

Соответственно, после года (**2005**), который всегда четыре символа[3] мне нужно все обрезать **((first reg. 1-2005))**
Ощущение, что ответ где то в голове есть, но не могу вспомнить метод

Пока остановился на методе split, вот кусок кода с парсера

```py
car_year = soup.find('tr', class_='field-year').find('span', class_='value').text.split
```

Comment: .split(" ", 1)[0]

Answer (score 3):

Может быть, если нет текста перед числом, то задать переменную `year_auto` и попробовать использовать *срез*:

```
year_auto = string[:3]
```

где `string` - это строка, которую передаем с сайта

Answer (score 0):

```
car_year, *_ = soup.find('tr', class_='field-year').find('span', class_='value').text.split()
```